# Ngrx store getting error as Property 'ofType' does not exist on type

Tags: ngrx, angular7, rxjs6, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to develop a application using `ngrx/store` getting error. unable to figureout the issue. any one help me?

here is my errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/store/effects/authentication.effects.ts(25,7): error TS2339: Property 'ofType' does not exist on type 'Actions<Action>'.
src/app/store/effects/authentication.effects.ts(29,59): error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/store/effects/authentication.effects.ts(29,74): error TS2339: Property 'password' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/store/effects/authentication.effects.ts(33,73): error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

typescript file :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Observable,  of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from './../../service/authentication.service';
import { AuthenticationActionTypes, 
         Login, LoginSuccess, 
         LoginFailure, Logout } from './../actions/authentication.actions';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationEffects {

    constructor(
        private actions:Actions, 
        private authenticationService:AuthenticationService,
        private router:Router) {}

    @Effect()
        Login: Observable<any> = this.actions
        .ofType(AuthenticationActionTypes.LOGIN)
        .pipe(
            map((action: Login) => action.payload),
            switchMap(payload => {
                return this.authenticationService.login(payload.email, payload.password)
            .pipe(
                map((user) => {
                console.log(user);
                return new LoginSuccess({token: user.token, email: payload.email});
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
                return of(new LoginFailure({ error: error }));
            }));
    }));

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
        LoginSuccess: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(AuthenticationActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
            tap((user) => {
              localStorage.setItem('token', user.payload.token);
              localStorage.setItem('email', user.payload.email);
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
            })
        );

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
        LoginFailure: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
            ofType(AuthenticationActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE)
        );

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
        public Logout: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
            ofType(AuthenticationActionTypes.LOGOUT),
                tap((user) => {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            localStorage.removeItem('email');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        })
    );

}
```

JSON File :

```
{
  "name": "authentication",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

any one help me here.... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

within your first effect you didn't put `ofType` into `pipe`:

so, instead of:

```
Login: Observable<any> = this.actions
        .ofType(AuthenticationActionTypes.LOGIN)
        .pipe(
```

do:

```
Login: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(AuthenticationActionTypes.LOGIN)
```

Comment: Answer is still relevant in 2020! [ Angular-8 | ngrx-8 ]

Comment: In NgRx 6.1 the ofType function was marked as deprecated in favor of the ofType operator, in NgRx v7 this function was dropped. See https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v7 about the removal of the ofType instance operator.